# Flutter: How change color of textfields if the passwords don't match?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new in flutter and I'm making a register form , I need change the color of password's textfields in real time if the passwords aren't equals, I may not be looking right, but I can't find how to do it (except one with `validator:`  but this doesn't work in `TextField`).

This is an example:

[image: The idea of what I want]

My code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'DashBoard.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
// import 'package:validators/validators.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController correo = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController celular = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwd = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwd2 = TextEditingController();

  Future register() async {
    var url =
        "http://192.168.1.139/mydatabase/register.php"; //IPv4, colocar después el hosting
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "correo": correo.text,
      "celular": celular.text,
      "passwd": passwd.text,
      "passwd2": passwd2.text
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text(
        'User allready exit!',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
      ));
    } else {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text('Registration Successful',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green)));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 900,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.blue[400],
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Correo',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: correo,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLength: 12,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  ],
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Celular',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: celular,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Contraseña',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: passwd,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: passwd2,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Text('Register',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        register();
                        passwd.text = "";
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: Text('Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My password's texfields have the controllers `passwd` and  `passwd2`. Any suggestion? Please that you can understand it well, I'm totally beginner in flutter. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out https://flutterforyou.com/how-to-change-textfield-border-color-in-flutter/

Comment: Sagar Acharya. thanks!!! I also wanted to change the border while I write, it was perfect!! Although I still don't understand how to do it if both passwords don't match. 
I think put some like this in both textfield within the "enabledBorder": 
`validator: if [passwd.text == passwd2.text] ? [borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)] : [borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0)],`
but I don't know how make this.

Comment: see first one is the actual password that you will be entering  and the second one is to verification one, so in second textfield you have to check in validator that if actual password and the verification password are same. if not you have to add the red border to the second textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.addListener` to the `TextEditingController` on `initState`.

A `bool` to change ui, you can use it to set borders color.

```dart
passwd2.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    showError = passwd2.text.isEmpty
        ? false
        : passwd.text.trim() != passwd2.text.trim();
  });
});
```

you can do the same for `passwd` with replacing the controller and it is only needed when you also want to change ui from 1st `TextFiled`

```
// try with commenting this part
passwd.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    showError = passwd.text.isEmpty
        ? false
        : passwd.text.trim() != passwd2.text.trim();
  });
});
```

And inside `Column` use this `showError` bool the way like, it can be

```dart
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    //........
    if (showError) const Text("Password didnot match"),
    //.......
```

More about [Listen to the controller for changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#listen-to-the-controller-for-changes)

Comment: It works perfect!! Thanks so much!! (I'll share my code)

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
  bool showError = false;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        passwd2.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            showError = passwd2.text.isEmpty
                ? false
                : passwd.text.trim() != passwd2.text.trim();
          });
        });
        passwd.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            showError = passwd.text.isEmpty
                ? false
                : passwd.text.trim() != passwd2.text.trim();
          });
        });
      }
    
    
     Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Contraseña',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[900], width: 2.0),
            ),
          ),
          controller: passwd,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Repita contraseña',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide:
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[900], width: 2.0),
            ),
          ),
          controller: passwd2,
        ),
      ),
      if (showError)
       const Text(
         "Las contraseñas no coinciden",
       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      )
```